# oracle out ref cursor to a loop

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor

How to pass the 'values' of the output cursor *o_cur* to a further loop?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_cursor (o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    script   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    script := 'select sysdate-1 notnow, sysdate today from dual union all select sysdate+1 notnow, sysdate today from dual';
    OPEN o_cur FOR script;

-- the question is related to this block:   
    for i in o_cur
    loop
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.notnow);
    end loop;
-----------------------

END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tanks to post of [Kaushik Nayak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7998591/kaushik-nayak), I found the acceptable solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_cursor (o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    script   VARCHAR2 (4000);
    type array is table of VARCHAR2(20) index by binary_integer;
    l_datapoint1 array;
    l_datapoint2 array;
BEGIN
    script := 'select sysdate-1 notnow, sysdate today from dual union all select sysdate+1 notnow, sysdate today from dual';
    OPEN o_cur FOR script;

    LOOP
        FETCH o_cur bulk collect into l_datapoint1, l_datapoint2;
          for i in 1 .. l_datapoint1.count
          loop
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_datapoint1(i) || ', ' || l_datapoint2(i) );
          end loop;
          exit when o_cur%notfound;
      end loop;
      close o_cur;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

`FETCH` is usually handled outside the procedure when the refcursor is an `OUT` variable

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dyn_cursor (o_cur OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
    script   VARCHAR2 (4000);
BEGIN
    script := 'select sysdate-1 notnow, sysdate today from dual union all select sysdate+1 notnow, sysdate today from dual';
    OPEN o_cur FOR script;

END;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
     v_cur      SYS_REFCURSOR;
     v_notnow   DATE;
     v_today    DATE;
BEGIN
     dyn_cursor(v_cur);
     LOOP
          FETCH v_cur INTO
               v_notnow,
               v_today;
          EXIT WHEN v_cur%notfound;
          dbms_output.put_line(v_notnow);
     END LOOP;
END;
/


02-10-18
04-10-18


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result in the same procedure without splitting _declaration of a procedure_ and _loop logic_ ? I tried to merge them but the results is: **ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence**

Comment: found the solution using fetch: `type array is table of VARCHAR2(20) index by binary_integer;
 l_datapoint1 array;
   l_datapoint2 array;
...
LOOP
          FETCH o_cur bulk collect into l_datapoint1, l_datapoint2 limit l_limit;
               for i in 1 .. l_datapoint1.count
          loop
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( l_datapoint1(i) || ', ' || l_datapoint2(i) );
          end loop;
          exit when o_cur%notfound;
      end loop;
      close o_cur;`

Comment: @tv : If you found my answer useful, please consider upvoting   it. Votes improve the value of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a strange construct. I would create a view you can reuse at different places.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_Times AS
    SELECT sysdate-1 notnow, sysdate today FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sysdate+1 notnow, sysdate today FROM dual;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OutputTime ()
IS
   CURSOR o_cur IS
     SELECT * FROM VW_Times;

BEGIN
   FOR i IN o_cur
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.notnow);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Idea is that the cursor is accumulated dynamically as a string which after that should be used in a loop! thanks for the purposed solution!

Comment: See: [String Aggregation Techniques](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques).